# Show $f$~$g$ iff $\overline {f}$~$\overline{g}$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $f$ be a path and $\overline{f}=f(1-t)$. Show $f$~$g$ iff  $\overline {f}$~$\overline{g}$ (by ~, I mean homotopic with respect to {$0,1$}.

My attempt: ($\Rightarrow$) Since $f$~$g$, there is a homotopy $F$ such that $F(s,0) = f(s)$ and $F(s,1) = g(s)$. Define $\overline {F} = F(1-s, t)$. Then clearly $\overline{F}$ satisfies the appropriate continuity requirements for a homotopy and $\overline{F}(s,0) = F(1-s,0) = f(1-s)= \overline{f}(s)$, and we have $\overline{F}(s,1) = F(1-s,1) = g(1-s)= \overline{g}(s)$. Now we just check that $\overline{F}(0,t)$ is the same $\forall t$ and that $\overline{F}(1,t)$ is the same $\forall t$. But $\overline{F}(0,t) = F(1,t)$, which is the same $\forall t$ by hypothesis, and $\overline{F}(1,t) = F(0,t)$, which is the same $\forall t$ by hypothesis. The ($\Leftarrow$) direction is similar.

Does this proof look right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good to me. Once you get the correct homotopy for the inverse paths (which you did), then the rest does follow quickly.

One nit-pick, if you used $t$ for your original parameter I would use $s$ for your homotopy parameter. It was a little confusing until I realized that $t$ had now become your homotopy parameter once you began the proof.